# How do I set a picture as a background image/wallpaper?

Tags: media

I've been trying to set a picture as a background image/wallpaper. I added the module 'Background Images' but am confused since it hasn't done anything. I tried pointing it to a new content type I created that has an image, but nothing happened. I installed Dynamic Background which did what I wanted to happen, but only for admin...

So without any access to the CSS files, is there a way to set a picture as a background wallpaper? I don't have access to the website's CSS, not even through FTP yet.

My knowledge on Drupal is very limited, so if you could have detailed explanations that would be great

Comment: This depends on your theme.  Some themes support configurable background images and others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Live CSS](http://drupal.org/project/live_css) module

> Edit CSS live within the page, and save the changes back to any css
>   file if you have write access.